# How can I know if a video has been manipulated/staged/faked?

Tags: editing

Recently, a video has been posted about a politician named Varoufakis sticking his [middle finger](https://youtu.be/MEUWxNifJJ8?t=40m47s) to Germany.

Later, a German TV host admitted faking Varoufakis 'middle finger' video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx-1LQu6mAE), showing some smart germans editing it using a software.

As a skeptic person, I'm not sure which one is the real one (statements of authority, videos uploaded do not really make me believe anything).

I only believe in evidence.

How can I know or basically prove (or be 99.999%) sure that a video is faked or staged using a software? What would be the methods or procedures? I would appreciate if a video professional would help me.

Comment: Hello fellow German! :) According to the Spiegel, the video you're talking about was indeed genuine and Böhmermann claims to have faked it are a mere scam (a good one though, I'll give him that)([source](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/tv/jan-boehmermann-zdf-sagt-varoufake-ist-satire-a-1024396.html)). To your question: if it's done really good, you can't know for sure. You could look for inregularities, e.g. misplayed shadows and things like that, but those can be faked as well ...

Answer (score 3):

Authenticity in video is dead.  It's been dead in photography for a long time.  It's just something we're all going to have to get used to.  Professional forensic analysis might sometimes disprove a video's authenticity, but it will never be able to conclusively prove it.

Comment: Unless you happen to have actually recorded it on tape that only works in a camcorder that doesn't have an input to record to tape from an external source, such as a TV or VCR.